# What sort of information can I discover about my DHCP server?

Tags: networking, dhcp

I want to probe my DHCP server to see what sort of information is publicly available. Is there a way to see things like, which pools my DHCP server services, lease expiration times, etc.? I'm on a mac.

The only useful information I can find so far, has been through `ipconfig getpacket en0`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1541) on `DHCP`, especially from `#section-2` and onwards.

> ...DHCP provides the mechanism for a client to acquire all of the IP configuration parameters that it needs in order to operate...

I guess for me it's the `...it needs in order to operate` part that suggests giving away info that is not needed in order to operate would not be done.

To be 100% positive of that for yourself, read the [RFC 1541](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1541) and the update [RFC 2131](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131)